# Do i need to maintain angular version compatibility while creating angular lib ?if yes, how?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-library

I have implemented a library in angular 8 but I need to use that in angular 7 application but am getting an error, please refer attached image

***error*** 
 core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at sgty-comment.js:55
    at Module../node_modules/@sgty/comment/fesm5/sgty-comment.js (sgty-comment.js:57)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/pages/curation/curation.module.ts (curation.component.ts:11)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
    at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:24
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)

[image]

Comment: its running fine for you in angular 8? can you give link to your library?

Comment: If you have used any components in your library which are not compatible with Angular 7, then there might be some issues. Try running the library in angular 8, if there are still issues, then it might not be a version compatibility issue.

Comment: yess in angular 8 it is working fine but not in angular  7

Comment: Please include error messages as text, not as pictures of text. Search engines cannot index text in images, to say nothing of visually impaired users.

Comment: you should add some code related to the error, as far I can see sgty isn't a public lib so no way to do any kind of diagnosis, also as @HereticMonkey mentioned, avoid using images